# Which variable type should be chosen type for .Find(LookAt: = xlPart/xlWhole)?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my problem. I would like my function to return a cell object which can be considered as the data start, depending if you look at the part of the string or at the whole word.

```
Function lookForDataStart(sht, word, searchtype as Variant)

    Set wordLocation = sht.Range("A1:D150").Find(word, LookAt:=searchtype)
    If Not (wordLocation Is Nothing) Then
        c = wordLocation.Column
        r = wordLocation.Row
        r = r + 1
        Do Until sht.Cells(r, c) <> ""
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        Set lookForDataStart = sht.Cells(r, c)
    Else
        Set lookForDataStart = Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

According to the documentation there is either xlPart or xlWhole parameter, which  are Variant types. When I try to use my function, e.g. Set `startCell = lookForDataStart(wks, sectionName, xlPart)` I am receiving 'Subscript out of range' error with empty value under `searchtype`. What is wrong here?

Comment: You may want to change Do Until sht.Cells(r, c) <> ""  as this could take you off the end of the sheet. Also, you should work with the populated range where possible.

Comment: I'd start by completing your `.Find` syntax - how come you use `LookAt:=` in one part of your argument, but you don't use `What:=` before `word`? I'd think it should be `.Find(What:=word, LookAt:=searchtype)`.

Comment: Is sht correctly defined? searchType in this instance will be passed as Long.

Comment: @QHarr Doesn't look like he ever sets `sht`. So he should also change the line to `Function lookForDataStart(sht As Worksheet, word As String, searchtype as Variant)` and add a `Set sht =` line..

Comment: @dwirony thanks for spotting that. It looks like I should do a break. It is working now, interesting that before it was working fine without What:=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked code based on the question detail.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim startCell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim word As String
word = "Test"
Dim searchtype As Variant
searchtype = "xlPart" 'xlWhole

Set startCell = lookForDataStart(sht, word, xlPart)
MsgBox startCell

End Sub


Function lookForDataStart(sht As Worksheet, word As String, searchtype As Variant)

    Set wordLocation = sht.Range("A1:D150").Find(word, LookAt:=searchtype)
    If Not (wordLocation Is Nothing) Then
        c = wordLocation.Column
        r = wordLocation.Row
        r = r + 1
        Do Until sht.Cells(r, c) <> ""
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        Set lookForDataStart = sht.Cells(r, c)
    Else
        Set lookForDataStart = Nothing
    End If

End Function
```